# nodejs / express: What is the best practice in running longer batch commands (that could take 45min or more)

Tags: node.js, express, loopback4

So, I have an Express API (with loopback.io) and what I want to do is run multi operations within one API call ... but API needs to return only if the job has started successfully.... then the node should continue doing and executing the job... until all the parts are done (the progress is also saving to DB, so the user can query the API at any time to see the progress - he will in fact be long pooling on the client side).

I want to know how can I handle this, I want the job to continue in case the server goes down meanwhile or anything ... checks the progress and continues the job..

what is the best practice to follow?

Comment: "Best practice" ends up being an opinion/context-dependent question. Continuing an aborted job can be handled in many different ways and in the end depends a lot on the nature of the job, how the job is being run, etc. I don't see how the question could be answered in a general way.

Comment: The only part there that sounds difficult is continuing after a server restart.  That involves continuously saving the state in a persistent store and then whenever your server restarts, it has to check the saved state to see if there are jobs to resume.  As has already been said, an answer to something like it not generic, but depends upon the precise details of what you're doing.  Since you include NO code at all, a complete answer here is not really possible.